# R: Define starting condition for continous value

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I´m trying to set up two new variables to incorporate into an existing data.frame which should be a running value starting at 1 (0) if a condition is met with respect to the IDs in the data.frame. So the data.frame is of similar structure to this:

```
ID   Var1
1     0
1     2 
1     5
1     12
2     0
2     2 
2     NA
2     11
```

and I want to get to:

```
ID  Var1   start   stop
1    0       0      0
1    2       0      1
1    5       1      2
1    12      2      3
2    0       0      0
2    2       0      1
2    NA      1      2
2    11      2      3
```

Start should be a running value, starting once `Var1 > 0` for the first time and stop should operate the same way. Start´s starting value should be 0 and stop´s starting value should be 1. It should further continue running, if Var1 takes on `NA` or `0` again in the course of the data.frame. I have tried doing the following:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(stop = ifelse(Var1 > 0, 
  0:nrow(df), 0))
```

But the variable it returns doesn´t start with 0, but with the number of the row the condition is first met in.

Comment: What if `NA` is at the beginning?

Comment: start & stop should only start the "counting" process once Var1 > 0, so if Var1 = NA at the beginning, this condition is not met. NA should be ignored tho if it occurs after the starting condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is base R option using `ave` + `replace`

```
transform(df,
  Start = ave(ave(replace(Var1, is.na(Var1), 0) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum) > 0, ID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(0, x))[-(length(x) + 1)]),
  Stop = ave(ave(replace(Var1, is.na(Var1), 0) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum)
)
```

or

```
transform(df,
  Start = ave(ave(ave(replace(Var1, is.na(Var1), 0) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum), ID, FUN = cumsum) > 1, ID, FUN = cumsum),
  Stop = ave(ave(replace(Var1, is.na(Var1), 0) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum) > 0, ID, FUN = cumsum)
)
```

which gives

```
  ID Var1 Start Stop
1  1    0     0    0
2  1    2     0    1
3  1    5     1    2
4  1   12     2    3
5  2    0     0    0
6  2    2     0    1
7  2   NA     1    2
8  2   11     2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't speak dplyr but you can easily adapt this, since data.table is only used for group-by.

```
DF <- read.table(text = "ID   Var1
1     0
1     2 
1     5
1     12
2     0
2     2 
2     NA
2     11", header = TRUE)

foo <- function(x) {
  #quantify leading zeros:
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  lead0 <- cumsum(x > 0) 
  nlead0 <- sum(lead0 == 0)
  
  #create result using sequence:
  list(c(rep.int(0, nlead0), sequence(length(x) - nlead0) - 1),
       c(rep.int(0, nlead0), sequence(length(x) - nlead0)))
}

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, c("start", "stop") := foo(Var1), by = ID]
#   ID Var1 start stop
#1:  1    0     0    0
#2:  1    2     0    1
#3:  1    5     1    2
#4:  1   12     2    3
#5:  2    0     0    0
#6:  2    2     0    1
#7:  2   NA     1    2
#8:  2   11     2    3
```